# Gingerbread -- how to wake up to 100% battery?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, charging, alarm

Apparently gingerbread stops charging when the battery gets to 100% . I guess this puts less wear on the battery. But it is kind of frustrating to wake up with a battery of only 70 or 80% given the that the battery life on these devices isn't great. On mine I never get 24 hours anymore, but that's probably due to daemons.

Maybe a charging schedule could be implemented in some way, like "next Alarm minus average charging time" ?

Comment: This does not sound like normal charging behavior, quite frankly. I would personally say that either your battery/charger has a physical defect or the sensors are not being read and interpreted correctly (though I have no evidence nor do I know you how to determine this for certain). That or I suppose it simply isn't charging long enough (seems unlikely).

Comment: Yeah, it should charge to 100% and then charge again at 95% or something like that, to keep it from going from 99% to 100% constantly. It shouldn't completely stop charging indefinitely when it hits 100% the first time.

Comment: Sounds like I've found a bug then! I am using an alternative ROM. Will report back if I find the cause

Answer (score 1):

It should wake up with anything between 95 and 100%. Anything less and either you're charger/battery/phone is doing something wrong.

Turning off the device and letting it sit in the charger (reconnect the charger) should fill the charge to 100% from whatever it it in a couple of minutes (10-30) while you wake up and get you're stuff.